# Math returns NaN

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make an particle move towards where on canvas was clicked however the formula returns NaN. Why is this and how can I fix this?

- step 1: Particle gets placed at player.x, player.y properly.
- step 2: At first tick the particle goes to the upper left point of the canvas  without x,y position.

[Screenie of particle props](http://2.1m.yt/Fdcu82gxt.png)

[example at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shadryck/c7nz591L/)

## Particle Object

```
function Shuriken(mouseX, mouseY) {
    this.rot = 0;
    this.vel = 2;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.x = player.x || WIDTH / 2;
    this.y = player.y || HEIGHT / 2;
    this.mouseX = mouseX || WIDTH /2;
    this.mouseY = mouseY || HEIGHT /2
    this.width = shurikenImg.width;
    this.height = shurikenImg.height;
}
```

## update on tick

```
Shuriken.prototype.move = function() {
    this.angle = Math.atan2(this.mouseY, this.x) * (180 / Math.PI);
    this.x += this.vel * Math.cos(this.angle);
    this.y += this.vel * Math.sin(this.angle);
}
```

Comment: also I would appreciate it if people who rage quickly could at least explain why they downvote this post.

Comment: What is the current value of player.x and player.y when Skuriken is called?

Comment: Something in the computation is apparently not what you expect it to be. You can drop a `console.log()` into that function to show the values involved in the computation to make sure they're not `null` or `undefined` etc.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I see why. Did you use breakpoints to debug your code step by step and check variables values everytime?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that you call  Math.atan2(this.mouseY, this.x) instead of  Math.atan2(this.mouseY, this.mouseX)

Comment: that depends on where the player is located at when the shuriken is created. However the player.x and player.y do work just fine before the update is called.

Comment: @Jeff Noel certainly tried to but to no avail.

Comment: @jmaster18 that shouldnt make any difference, the x is the same for this.x and mouseX isnt it? [Math.atan2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2)

Comment: @shadryck They do work fine, but they do that work as strings and not numbers, is what I expect. Without more console.logging, and more information on the state of the variables, we can't exactly know what's happening, but somewhere, I suspect there's a string with a number that you're trying to treat as a pure number, like '4' instead of 4

Comment: @shadryck If the values are not changed by another function or event handler then you're right. Place a debugger statement on your code and use your browser's developer console to check the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You convert `angle` from radians into degrees. Nicer to debug (because degrees are still taught in school) but alas, the `sin` and `cos` in the next lines expect their arguments to be in radians again. Granted, the functions ought still to work; but the values you get are no longer what you expect.
2. `this.vel` is undefined in the jsfiddle. This is most likely what lead to the observed `NaN`.
3. This is a wrong calculation:

   ```
   this.x = this.vel * Math.cos(this.angle);
   this.y = this.vel * Math.sin(this.angle);
   ```

   You don't *want* the x and y positions calculated this way. Add or subtract the (adjusted) velocity from the x/y coordinates.

Comment: You are right, the missing this.vel seem the have caused the Nan. Alright, trying it that way. Removing the player coords from the mouse coords before processing it. NOTE: misread, you meant the +=

Comment: @shadryck: Glad to be of help! With the positions update changed to `this.x += ..` and the angle based on the *current* mouse position, I got a quite interesting control over the shuriken *after* firing: I could still influence its path. I wasn't sure if that was intentional, so I did not try changing that part.

Comment: haha could give it some freaky effects that way yes however that was not as planned. It should have been like this. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shadryck/c7nz591L/15/) Next step is collision detection with monsters.